# Redirect https://www to https

Tags: nginx

I've tried following other questions on here and on digital ocean but none have worked for me. I'm using nginx and so far if I type [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) the page fails to load but when I try with https it works. How can I redirect www to https? I've attempted to do this in server block 3.

Nginx config:

```
   # Server block 1
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }
}


upstream my_nodejs_upstream {
 server 127.0.0.1:5000;
 keepalive 64;
}

# Server block 2
server {

        root /var/www/html;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name example.com; # managed by Certbot

        location / {
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
                proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
                proxy_pass http://my_nodejs_upstream/;
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_read_timeout 240s;
        }

        location /api {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}
# Server block 3
    server {
        if ($host = example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        } # managed by Certbot
    
        if ($host = www.example.com) {
            return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
        }
    
            listen 80 ;
            listen [::]:80 ;
        server_name www.example.com example.com;
        return 404; # managed by Certbot
    
    
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not just make www a CNAME to @ in DNS and call it a day?

Comment: I have two a records for my domain one www.example.com and example.com. When I visit www.example.com I get "connection is not private"

Comment: Yep, so most likely your SSL certificate is only good for example.com and doesn't have a SAN for www.example.com. Are you using LetsEncrypt? If so you have to explicitly declare the www. Try running `openssl s_client -connect example.com:443 </dev/null 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -text | grep DNS:` and see what names the certificate covers.

Comment: Yeah the dns only covers example.com. Would I need to register another ssl for www.example.com?

Comment: They can be on the same certificate, you just have to specify it on there - typically a commercial certificate will automatically cover www as well, though not always. Is it a commercial certificate you bought, or LetsEncrypt?

Comment: Let's encrypt and using certbot

Comment: [Take a look at this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41097696/letsencrypt-certificate-for-www-and-non-www-domain) and give extending it to cover the subdomain (www) a try.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much!

Comment: The actual answer doesn't actually solve the issue. It should be updated to contain the real fix.